# Why this preg_match evaluate spaces?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have this preg_match, but i can't understand why, it is evaluating for spaces:

```
preg_match('/[\'^\"^\0-9^£$%&*()!·¢∞&÷“≠´}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/'
```

i want to verify if there is any of those characters but allowing the spaces, sorry i am no so good with regex, i know that the space in regex is \s, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\0-9` is not making a range of numbers. Use `\d` or `0-9`, without the backslash. You also don't need to escape the double quote, and you only need to list each character once, `>` and `^` were listed more than once. If you were trying to pair them with the preceding character that won't work. You could use an optional grouping for that `(this|that)`. Every character in a character class is individual with the exception of ranges (and because of that be careful with the `-`).

This should function as you expect your current regex to:

```
[\'^"0-9£$%&*()!·¢∞&÷“≠´}{@#~?<>,|=_+¬-]
```